# Save FormulaArray Evaluation to an Actual Array

Tags: excel, vba

***Background:***

I need to retrieve the values that an array formula (in the excel interface) calculates in order to loop through the results there.

***Problem:***

I have not found a way on how to store all the values that it calculates. I can store only the first one.

***Code:***

```
Sub test()
Dim ArrTopValues() As Long
    'Fails
    ArrTopValues = Application.Evaluate("=LARGE(A1:A11,{1,2,3})")
End Sub
```

I need to work with the 3 values that the formula can hold on the excel interface by pressing "F9"

***Further thoughts***

I know that I can write a UDF that recreates the Large function (or even that just evaluates the "k" on the Large function and build the Array variable that way). Please understand that I am looking how to store this array evaluations for more scenarios and a workaround to solve this has been done already to "make it work".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use INDEX to return the array and you need to make the array a variant:

```
Sub test()
Dim ArrTopValues()
    ArrTopValues = Application.Evaluate("=INDEX(LARGE(A1:A11,{1,2,3}),0)")

End Sub
```

Comment: This is the one! Thanks!